# R: recode multiple columns based on matching a key

Tags: r, key, lapply

I have a data frame with multiple columns and a vector with a key to the correct answer for each of those columns.

```
ID <- c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4")
A <- c(1,3,2,1)
B <- c(3,2,2,3)
C <- c(1,2,2,2)
D <- c(3,3,1,2)

df <- data.frame(ID,A,B,C,D)
df

#    ID A B C D
# 1 ID1 1 3 1 3
# 2 ID2 3 2 2 3
# 3 ID3 2 2 2 1
# 4 ID4 1 3 2 2

key <- c(1,2,2,3)
```

I would like to recode the dataframe so that if a data point in a column matches the correct answer for that column in the key, the output is 1, and if there is no match, the output is 0. My desired output would thus look like this:

```
#    ID A B C D
# 1 ID1 1 0 0 1
# 2 ID2 0 1 1 1
# 3 ID3 0 1 1 0
# 4 ID4 1 0 1 0
```

I'd prefer code that can do this for all columns at once, since my actual dataset has quite a few more columns than this. I'm guessing an `lapply` could work, but I don't know how to iterate it so that each element in the key vector matches with the correct column in the dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replicate the `key` and then do `==` to create a logical matrix, coerce it to binary with `+` (No packages used)

```
df[-1] <- +( df[-1] == key[col(df[-1])])
```

-output

```
df
#   ID A B C D
#1 ID1 1 0 0 1
#2 ID2 0 1 1 1
#3 ID3 0 1 1 0
#4 ID4 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: nice solution! could you explain why `key` can accept a matrix object in the bracket and how why it produce the array [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ?

Comment: @KabochaPorter Is your question related to `+(`

Comment: I am not understanding this part: `key[col(df[-1])])` the object inside the `[]` is matrix while key is an array.

Comment: @KabochaPorter The `row/col` functions returns  matrix of row/column index which can be used for replicating each element of key.  In this case,each element of key is replicated 4 times, as col(df[-1]) will have first column 1, second column 2, ....   This is to make the comparison lengths same for elementwise comparison

Comment: @KabochaPorter  Just to understand how it works, `c(5, 3, 7)[c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)]` replicates the element values based on the position index vector

Answer (score 2):

One strategy with `tidyverse`

```r
ID <- c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4")
A <- c(1,3,2,1)
B <- c(3,2,2,3)
C <- c(1,2,2,2)
D <- c(3,3,1,2)

df <- data.frame(ID,A,B,C,D)
df
#>    ID A B C D
#> 1 ID1 1 3 1 3
#> 2 ID2 3 2 2 3
#> 3 ID3 2 2 2 1
#> 4 ID4 1 3 2 2

key <- c(1,2,2,3)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% nest(attempt = c(A, B, C, D)) %>%
  mutate(new = map(attempt, ~setNames(+(.x == key), LETTERS[1:4])),
         score = map_int(attempt, ~ sum(.x == key))) %>%
  unnest_wider(new)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   ID    attempt                  A     B     C     D score
#>   <chr> <list>               <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 ID1   <tibble[,4] [1 x 4]>     1     0     0     1     2
#> 2 ID2   <tibble[,4] [1 x 4]>     0     1     1     1     3
#> 3 ID3   <tibble[,4] [1 x 4]>     0     1     1     0     2
#> 4 ID4   <tibble[,4] [1 x 4]>     1     0     1     0     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>